# How to use or reinstall the android emulator in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

When I compile sometimes the output returns to me: your version of android emulator is out of date. if I just recompile after it compiles without error. Sometimes it moves on another screen (I have 3) and systematic plant.withe error qemu-system-x86_64.exe i tryed to change the graphic source but didnt working One of the solutions that works is to reset the emulator in android device manager.

I then found Visual Studio Emulator that did not work either I uninstall them and I can not reinstall it

I repair uninstall reinstall visual studio.

What is the best way to use an emulator

Comment: i found this he talking about ndk and the path. my ndk path is empty but i dont found in my computer :/
https://aleksandarsimic.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-forms/

Comment: it looks like I am also a victim of a bog 4 years old
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/f92bb80e-bf32-42f8-bd2c-2c7b8f9e840b?category=visualstudiogeneral and stay actif

Comment: Have you tried create a new emulator from [device-manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows)?

Comment: yes I have install and uninstall several I change version I try to set them with more or less memory or compatibility. and I also receive the error of the update. I try also genymotion that does not work in my case and in addition is paying. I also tried live player which finds reference object errors that I do not have with the emulator. in my research I found that it was maybe my i5 6400 processor or my gtx 980 graphics card. so I continue to reset each startup and wait a very long time each deployment

Comment: i have always this error